# Securing Spark Job on Cluster

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark

I was dealing with one the spark requirement here where Client (like Banking Client where security is major concern) needs all spark processing should happen securely.

For example all communication happening between spark client and server ( driver & executor communication) should be on secure channel. Even when spark spills on disk based on storage level (Mem+Disk), it should not be written in un-encrypted format on local disk or there should be some workaround to prevent spill.

I did some research  but could not get any concrete solution.Let me know if someone has done this.

Any guidance would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the right job to implement [Apache Commons Crypto](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/)

Instead of preventing the spill, that usually happens during the shuffle phase, you can implement the Crypto library to encrypt the output that is spilled.

Here are a few recommended reads:

1. [Securing Apache Spark Shuffle using Apache Commons Crypto](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/08/securing-apache-spark-shuffle-using-apache-commons-crypto/)
2. [Spark Encryption](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/sg_spark_encryption.html)

JAVA based examples

1. [CipherByteBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/CipherByteBufferExample.html)
2. [Stream Example](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/xref-test/org/apache/commons/crypto/examples/StreamExample.html)

These examples are in Java I don't think you should have any problem in implementing them with Spark/Scala as well. I haven't implemented them myself so I am not sure of any underlying issues etc.

Comment: This looks interesting example. Can you point me some example ? like how do I use in Spark job?

Comment: Thank. I will try that.